# Soundness and Completeness of the d-separation

Tags: probability, graph-theory, bayesian-network

I was reading Koller's book on Probabilistic Graphical Models and was wondering how to prove soundness and completeness of the d-separation ?

Let me explain what is d-separation and it's properties soundness and completeness which needs to be proved in order to prove d-separation.

d-separation has been based on intuitions regarding flow of influence in Bayesian Networks (BN). In other words there is no grantee that d-separation is "correct."
Perhaps there is a distribution over the BN where X can influence Y despite the fact that all trails between them are blocked.

Hence, the first property we want to ensure for d-separation as a method for determining independence is **soundness**: if we find that two nodes X and Y are d-separated given some Z, then we are guaranteed that they are, in fact, conditionally independent given Z.

**Theorem**: If a distribution P factorizes according to G, then I(G) ⊆ I(P).

In other words, any independence reported by d-separation is satisfied by the underlying distribution.

A second desirable property is the complementary one — **completeness**: d-separation detects all possible independencies.  More precisely, if we have that two variables X and Y are independent
given Z, then they are d-separated. A careful examination of the completeness property reveals that it is ill defined, inasmuch as it does not specify the distribution in which X and Y are independent.

To formalize this property, we first define the following notion:
A distribution P is faithful to G if, whenever (X ⊥ Y | Z) ∈ I(P), then d-sepG(X; Y | Z). In other words, any independence in P is reflected in the d-separation properties of the graph.

We can now provide one candidate formalization of the completeness property is as follows:

- For any distribution P that factorizes over G, we have that P is faithful to G; that is, if X and Y are not d-separated given Z in G, then X and Y are dependent in all distributions P that factorize over G.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some insight of what you need for those (like me) who are not familiar with this book? I know d-separation as a definition and I do not see what you mean by soundness and completeness ...

Comment: @wece Sorry for late response. I edited the question hope it is more clear now. Also more information is available on [link](https://github.com/JimmyLin192/GraphicalModel). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry this answer is pretty late, but maybe it is interesting to those that still take a look at this question.

**Soundness** was prooven by Verma and Pearl in the following paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.2379.pdf) and the proof for **completeness** can be found in the following paper written by Christopher Meek (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4973.pdf).